# What model is appropriate for predicting time series trends?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a tme series that when particularly anomalies the overall trend will be either higher or lower than before it started picking up these anomalies. I don't need to predict exactly what value it will have, just the trend.

What model is appropriate for this kind of situation? I have never run across this before.

**EDIT: Additional Info Of What I am looking for**

Let's call the variable I am interested in is $f$, which at some time $t$, takes on the value $f_t$. I want to know if $f_{t+\delta t}$ is higher or lower than $f_t$ based on anomalies/outliers I pick up from another variable, called $x$. So I supposed the model looks something like $f_{t+\delta t}(x_t)=x_t+x_{t-1}+..$

But this feels awkward to me, what kind of model(s) should I consider?

Comment: Do you know when the anomalies occured (both historically and in the future), or do you need to detect this in the historical data?

Comment: I have training data where i know these anomalies occurred but i will need to detect these live for my trend forecasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, you can probably use linear [splines](/questions/tagged/splines) to transform time. Here are some random data:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- seq(0,4,by=0.05)
obs <- sin(xx*pi/2)+rnorm(length(xx),0,0.2)
plot(xx,obs,type="o",xlab="",ylab="")
```

[image]

Assume that we know the trend changes at times $1$ and $3$. We can then include linear spline terms of the form

$$ (t-1)_+=\max\{t-1,0\}\quad\text{and}\quad (t-3)_+=\max\{t-3,0\}$$

along with the linear time trend predictor $t$ itself:

```
spline.regressors <- cbind(
    xx,
    pmax(xx-1,0),
    pmax(xx-3,0)
)

model <- lm(obs~spline.regressors)

plot(xx,obs,type="o",xlab="",ylab="")
lines(xx,predict(model),lwd=2,col="red")
```

[image]

*Regression Modeling Strategies* by Frank Harrell, section 2.4.2, contains more information.

You might also be able to include your trend changes in a state space model, which would be analogous to adding new components to an exponential smoothing model.

To *detect* these changes, look at methods for detecting [structural-change](/questions/tagged/structural-change). Most of these are built to detect *level* changes (i.e., step changes), not changes in trend - so just apply these methods to your series after differencing it. In R, the [`strucchange` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html) is helpful, and even if you don't use R, it contains some good pointers to literature.

Alternatively, you could use control theory and construct a [control-chart](/questions/tagged/control-chart). Whenever a series is out of control and goes out of your control bounds with a consistent trend, its underlying trend probably has changed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I also added more details in my question before I saw your answer if it helps. Not sure if your answer is still applicable in that case.